# Where can i find documentation on the db schema

Tags: postgresql, documentation, ory, ory-hydra

I want to know the work of each table for ory hydra and want to know the task each table performs where can i find the documentation for this?

I checked the ory hydra website and checked through the github repo discussion.

Answer (score 1):

For any application, the documentation is usually a comprehensive guide for end-users to use the application. It answers queries and helps with common issues and troubleshooting. The internal specifications and working intricacies of the application will not be mentioned there.

I would recommend exploring the code base on GitHub. You can gain insights into how the schema is structured and how it interacts with the rest of the application. Go through the comments in the code and the readme files.

You could make use of the active ory/hydra community by creating an issue on the repository. When creating the issue, be sure to select relevant tags and provide a clear description of your intention to learn more about the DB schema. You could use the `rfc` (Request for Comments) tag, as it encourages discussion and idea-sharing within the community. It might also serve as a good starting point for you to be a part of the community and contribute to ory/hydra.